How to correctly create the connection to a local SQL Server database using TypeORM for Langchain?
I am trying to connect to my local SQL Server database to use it with Langchain. This is how I am trying to create the connection but keep getting the error shown below when fromDataSourceParams runs:
const datasource = new DataSource({

    type: 'mssql',
    host: 'localhost',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    database: 'DB',
    logging: true,
    extra: { trustServerCertificate: true },
  });
  const db = await SqlDatabase.fromDataSourceParams({ appDataSource: datasource });


err = new ConnectionError(err)
ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.

What am I doing wrong when am I creating the connection?
Tried to use my Windows credentials for username and password and be able to connect to the database.

Normally when you specify username and password properties that's telling the driver to use SQL Login authentication with the SQL Server, which is different than Windows authentication. (You cannot mix the two.) What happens if you entirely remove the username and password properties?

Removed username and password but still getting exactly the same error.
err = new ConnectionError(err)
ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.

If you're needing Windows authentication are you using the specific mssql/msnodesqlv8 driver? See the "Windows Authentication Example Using MSNodeSQLv8" section in the mssql package documentation.

I have established db connection as below


 datasource = new DataSource({
          type: "mssql",
          host: this.sqlserverhost,
          port: this.sqlPort,
          database: this.sqldb,
          username: this.sqlusername,
          password: this.sqlpwd,
          domain: this.sqlDomain,
          options: {
            trustedConnection: true,
          },
          extra: {
            trustServerCertificate: true,
          },
        });



specify the domain and local host

options does not have trustedConnection property. Also I dont have a username or password for the localhost. Would it be my windows credentials? This is the closest I got and still getting the same error.
const datasource = new DataSource({
url: DATABASE_URL,
type: 'mssql',
host: 'localhost',
database: 'DB',
domain: 'localhost',
options: { trustServerCertificate: true },
extra: {
trustServerCertificate: true,
},
});

have you connected with SQL server management studio to verify your connection

Yes I did. I can easily query data with other ORMs. I tried connecting TypeOrm to MySQL and it works fine but MSSQL is giving issues.
